# Ticking sound produced when adjusting voltage on a lab dc power supply

Tags: power-supply, dc

when you adjust the voltage on a dc power supply, at certain stages you can hear a ticking sound. i was wondering what is the source of that sound. this happens on all the power supplies in the lab, so it's not the power supply malfunctioning.

Comment: Ffs, _stop_ writing pointless one-liner answers in the comment section. They serve absolutely no purpose. If a question is simple enough to answer with a one-liner, someone will obviously write a real answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As you adjust the output voltage, the logic inside the power supply is using relays to select different taps on the power transformer to change the input voltage going to the linear regulator. This helps keep the dissipation of the regulator within reasonable limits.

A power supply that uses a switching regulator will typically not require relays for range switching.